# Best way to manage releases in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am managing releases for a team of 8 developers.  We have three environments:
DEV - where we all make our changes
UAT - an environment for users to test changes
LIVE - live environment

We use Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2017.

Developers make changes to files and submit them for release to UAT by emailing a list (sometimes with a changeset number).  Sometimes different users will make changes to the same files but not all changes should be released.

Once tested in UAT, the changes are released to Live however sometimes a file needs to move from UAT to Live that has earlier changes in it that are not approved for Live release yet.

Please could I ask users' advice as to what the best way for managing this process should be?  Unintended changes keep getting released to UAT or Live when they should remain in DEV or UAT.

Any advice would be very welcome.  Thanks

Comment: I would try to create a branch for each simple feature and merge those branches into your MAIN branch. It is an arduous journey with many obstacles and perilous danger, which I have been involved in closely for the better part of 3 years. Invest some time into this article and circle back with questions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of "the best way" question is primarily opinion-based  and hard to answer.

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

*Developers make changes to files and submit them for release to UAT by emailing a list (sometimes with a changeset number).*

For this scenario, instead of using E-Mail to send lists, perhaps you could use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-GenerateReleaseNotes-Task)

This extension is a build task you can use in build steps. This task generates a markdown release notes file based on a template passed into the tool. Here is an example of release notes output:

> Release notes for build SampleSolution.Master
>
> Build Number: 20160229.3 Build started: 29/02/16 15:47:58 Source
>   Branch: refs/heads/master
>
> Associated work items
>
> Task 60 [Assigned by: Bill ] Design WP8 client Associated change
>   sets/commits
>
> ID bf9be94e61f71f87cb068353f58e860b982a2b4b Added a template ID
>   8c3f8f9817606e48f37f8e6d25b5a212230d7a86 Start of the project

The suggestion on the comment is a way that fits your needs and your circumstances. You could create three branches stands for your three environments. And for each branch you could use branch policy(GIT) which will protect your branches and avoid unintended changes merged to UAT and Live.

Since the TFS system or any other tool is hard to judge whether some files are approved or not to release yet. It' based on your team management, you could use **permissions**  in TFS to limit users who have access to deployment or do the release. For example only PM and team leader could handle this. Combine with work items, charts , test management, reports and other functions in TFS.

Note Team Foundation Server is a product that not only provides source code management,build, release, but also reporting, requirements management, project management (for both agile software development and waterfall teams), lab management and testing  capabilities. It **covers the entire application lifecycle**, and enables DevOps capabilities.

Suggest you first go through the [Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/) in TFS and also take a look at how to [configure your release pipelines for multiple environments deployments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/24/configuring-your-release-pipelines-for-safe-deployments/)